# I've problem with electrron-vue and I need a solution

Tags: electron-vue

I've installed `electron-vue` to use vue with `electron-app`. When I wrote the following command `npm run dev` an error was shown to me, I found listing directory instead of the `LandingPage`.

Comment: Please read [ask]  and [edit] your question accordingly. Fix the totally pointless title. Add the code you have. Add the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

The electron-vue is not being updated at this time. (currently, electronic version 2.x)

There's a boilerplate that I forked the electron-vue and updated all the modules with the latest modules. The use method is the same and we have added the ui framework and css-precessor.

- Electron 5
- Vue-CLI 3
- Babel 7
- Vue 2.6
- css-preprocessor

  - Sass
  - Less
  - Stylus
- UI Framework

  - Quasar 1.x
  - Vuteify 2.x

We recommend you try it.

https://github.com/kdydesign/vue-electron5